# How to format the double values in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, format

I have done some research on this and found solutions for string formatting only. Im trying to format a decimal number with trailing 0's, without any conversion to String.

For example: 0.439  --> 0.4390

How can this be done?

I am populating a table with decimal numbers. I just wish it to look neat.

Comment: If you just want to display it, why can't it be converted to String?

Comment: @user3437460  I am populating a table with decimal number. I just wish it to look neat.

Comment: Just use those approach you found. String.format() or DecimalFormat. If you are populating a sql table, then you can use a different tag and ask about how to format numbers in a table.

Comment: @user3437460 does not work when the table model is double. I am populating the numbers dynamically

Comment: What table are you referring to? SQL?

Comment: @Milan Why do you think using string looks ugly?

Comment: @user3437460 I am refering to TableView in JavaFX

Comment: You want to have a formatted number (aka a String) without converting it into a String?

Comment: @SkrewEverything Never said string looks ugly. I am dynamically populating the table with double values. and wish to format it with training 0's

Comment: So what OP actually want to ask is "How to format the double values in JavaFX TableView" and not "How to format double values without converting to String".

Comment: @brummfondel that is correct

Comment: @user3437460 sorry, thought it never made a diffirence

Comment: @Milan Then you can convert the double to string before displaying. And what do you meant by "*I just wish it to look neat.*"?

Comment: @SkrewEverything did that already and it skrewed me with errors

Comment: @Milan JavaFX TableView allows fields with String type, perhaps you can display your values as Strings? Unless you have other reasons for not being able to set that particular field as String. You may want to shows an image of your current Table.

Comment: @user3437460 let me try decimal format

Comment: @Milan Can you show us the code where it gives you errors while using double to string conversion?

Comment: @Milan Are you using `SimpleStringProperty` as your field type?

Comment: @user3437460 Sorry I am unable to show any code here. Nope I am using an arrayList which is of type Double and my whole table is of type Double.

Comment: @SkrewEverything the error which I am getting: https://jpst.it/PAlx

Comment: "I am unable to show any code here". Huh? Why can't you show code? If you can't be bothered to write some code to demonstrate the issue you are facing, why would you expect anyone to take the time to help you?

Comment: @brummfondel The OP is asking how to format the display of the data without changing the type of the representation of the data. I.e. (s)he presumably needs the data represented in the data layer as a numeric type (to do arithmetic, etc) but want the table to display that value in a formatted way. So a paraphrased form of the question is "what is the mechanism in a JavaFX table view for separating data representation from the display of the data".

Answer (score 0):

> @Milan Are you using SimpleStringProperty as your field type?
>
> Nope I am using an arrayList

It is not that the formatting by using `String.format()` or `DecimalFormat` class is not working. It is because the field in your Table Model is not of type `String`.

After getting your double values formatted to string, you still have to convert it to the type similar to your Table field.

Comment: @Milan you may want to paste your TableModel code in the link as well..

Comment: You should not change the data type simply for the convenience of displaying it the way you want. If the data are numeric, you need to keep them as a numeric data type. Else you will find you have to do all sorts of type conversions when you actually need to use the data somewhere.

Comment: No, I am not advising OP to change the type of the field.

Comment: "It is because the field in your Table Model is not of type `String`" seems to imply you think it should be changed to a string...

Comment: That just tells OP what is probably causing the error.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to perform calculation and send result as double to your table/api you can use BigDecimal. So you can set rounding, digits, etc. Then get as double value.

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(1.0);
d = d.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
d = d.multiply(new BigDecimal(2.0));
double tableValue = d.doubleValue();
```